# dynamic image binding in Vuejs: https:/blah/${item.img}

Tags: image, vue.js, dynamic, binding

I can't for the life of me figure out how to dynamically bind an image in Vuejs form an external site.

I have the following code which is working properly.

```
<v-btn
    v-for="item in items"
    :key="item.id"
    :to="item.path"
    color="white"
    class="brand-btn"
  >
    <v-img :src="require(`@/assets/${item.img}`)" contain></v-img>
  </v-btn>
```

My team decided to host the images on an external site, eg., https://thisisanexternalsite.com/images/item01.jpg

Does "require" work on external sites?  i tried it and it doesn't seem to work:

```
<v-img :src="require(`https://thisisanexternalsite.com/images/${item.img}`)" contain></v-img>
```

This one doesn't work as well:

```
<v-img :src="`https://thisisanexternalsite.com/images/${item.img}`" contain></v-img>
```

nor this one:

```
<v-img :src="'https://thisisanexternalsite.com/images/' + item.img" contain></v-img>
```

I am pretty sure I am missing something really obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Boo.  My sincerest apologies but it was just a simple typo of the url but to answer my question, these work as intended.

```
<v-img :src="`https://thisisanexternalsite.com/images/${item.img}`" contain></v-img>
```

and this one as well

```
<v-img :src="'https://thisisanexternalsite.com/images/' + item.img" contain></v-img>
```

I'll try to be more careful next time. Cheers.